# Rails demo app on local host not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

New to Rails. Everything solid through creation of demo_app, but rails server is yielding just the basic rails welcome page, not my demo application

Comment: Did you change the root to your own controller action in config/routes.rb? `root :to => 'home#index'`?

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

You need to delete `public/index.html` and change `root to:` in `config/routes.rb` to point to your welcome page's controller action.

Answer (score 0):

Well, then Rails works :)

In your console cd to the Folder where your rails app is and run

```
    rake routes
```

Then try out one of the routes in your browser. 
If there aren't any, you have to create routes. Follow some tutorial for this.